# Fetch in react native not send the post

Tags: php, post, react-native, request

Hello I am trying to send post variables to my API and I not getting the post data in the PHP file

This is my react native code:

```
let data = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'firstname': 'test',
    }),
}
fetch(GLOBALS.API + '/registerApi.php?key=' + GLOBALS.KEY, data)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Alert Title',
      responseJson.output
    )

})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

It's returning me empty: `[]`

```
$array = array(
    "output" => json_encode($_POST)
);
$output = json_encode($array);
die($output);
```

When I use `$_REQUEST` it's returning me only the `key` get parameter without the `firstname` one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PHP, you need to use

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7):

JSON.stringify did not work for me, try using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead to prepare data for sending. Here is example:

```
import FormData from 'FormData';

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('firstname', 'test');

let data = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: formData
}

fetch(api_url, data)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseJson => console.log('response:', responseJson))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Can you give me a link for this module please ?
`import FormData from 'FormData';`

Comment: And how to recive data on server side in you case ?

Comment: This is about Fetch, and Fetch is used on client side. Is already in React Native, this is not external module.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is JSON.stringify.**
**Use FormData instead.** No need to install, it's not 3rd party. It works for me.

```
import FormData from 'FormData';

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('username', 'Andy');

...

{ 
  ... 
  body: formData 
  ... 
}
```